# getting value of input type button in php

Tags: php, button

I wrote this code but the problem is that when I press the "Change background" button, nothing changes but I should be able to see some part of contents after I pressed it.

```
<form name="change "action="index.php" method="get">
        <center><a href="index.php"><button type="button">REFRESH THE PAGE!!</button></a></center><br/>
        <center><b>WELCOME NOTE!!</b></center><br/>
        <center><textarea readonly="readonly" name="textarea" rows="6" cols="50" style="color:blue; font-size:15pt">Each day holds a surprise. But only if we expect it can we see, hear, or feel it when it comes to us. Let's not be afraid to receive each day's surprise, whether it comes to us as sorrow or as joy It will open a new place in our hearts, a place where we can welcome new friends and celebrate more fully our shared humanity.</textarea></center>
<br/>

<?php

        mysql_connect("localhost","DB","password") or die("ERROR!!");
        mysql_select_db("DB") or die("COULDN'T FIND IT!!") or die("COULDN'T FIND DB"); 


        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM background");

        $id = 'ID';
        $Blue = 'blue';
        $White = 'white';
        $Silver = 'silver';
        $Red = 'red';
        $text=$_GET['textarea'];

        while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){


            if (isset( $_SESSION['CurrentUser'])){

            echo '<center><button type="button" name="background">Change background</button>';
            echo '<button type="button" name="color">Change font color</button>';
            echo '<button type="button" name="size">Change font size</button></center><br/>'; 

                if (isset( $_GET['background'])){ 
                echo '<span>Choose background color</span><br/>';
                echo '<a href="?colour='.$Blue.'"><img src="red.png"></a>'; 
                echo '<a href="?colour='.$White.'"><img src="white.jpg"></a>'; 
                echo '<a href="?colour='.$Silver.'"><img src="silver.jpg"></a>';
                echo '<a href="?colour='.$Red.'"><img src="red.png"></a>'; }

            }               

    }
    ?>

    </form>


    </td></tr></table>
```

Program doesn't see this part;

```
if (isset( $_GET['background'])){ 
                    echo '<span>Choose background color</span><br/>';
                    echo '<a href="?colour='.$Blue.'"><img src="red.png"></a>'; 
                    echo '<a href="?colour='.$White.'"><img src="white.jpg"></a>'; 
                    echo '<a href="?colour='.$Silver.'"><img src="silver.jpg"></a>';
                    echo '<a href="?colour='.$Red.'"><img src="red.png"></a>'; }
```

Comment: I do wanna point out that `mysql` functions depricated

Comment: @Dorvalla yeah but I need it. That's what my instructor wants me to do it.

Comment: You'd better format your code in order to be understandable... The half of it is hidden behind the scroll...

Comment: @Al.G. that's unnecessary part. It's just a text.

Comment: Mysql_* fonksiyonlarini birakmalisin. Pdo veya mysqli kullanmalisin.

Comment: @HddnTHA Please use English only on SO

Comment: @andrew It is not an answer it is a comment and i can use my main language.

Comment: [SO's official stance is that you can use not-English, yes](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/), but as pointed out in a meta post, [more people will understand what you mean if you use English, even broken English.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because form cannot be submited without submit button:
Replace  `<button type="button"` with `<button type="submit"`

BTW use `mysqli_` instead of `mysql_` because it is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Change

```
  if (isset( $_GET['background'])){
```

TO

```
 if (isset( $_GET['colour'])){
```

and see what happens.

END EDIT.

Quick question...
does your link have the "background" variable defined in it?

...page.php?background=1;

If the program doesn't see that part then you need to work your way up through the conditions and see what condition it isn't meeting.
Either...

A) ?background=1 is not set in the link

B) session CurrentUser was not set

C)Your mysql is returning 0 rows

Comment: The thing is that when I log in to the database, I see those "Change background", "Change font color", "Change font size" buttons so my session works well the problem is that when I press the "Change background" button after logged on, I can't see the "if (isset( $_GET['background']))" part.

Comment: Try the above edit and see what happens. You are setting the link to ?colour but then looking for ?background.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting background variable to the page. Check url once. You can debug it by using the length of variable by strlen($_GET['background']) . Also print_r($_GET) will print all the variables received by the page